# git svn clone fails when called with --preserve-empty-dirs argument

Tags: git, git-svn, git-clone, svn2git

I'm migrating our SVN to Git. Our Jenkins job expects a specific folder, which in some branches can be empty. Thus, I have provided the --preserve-empty-dirs argument to the `git svn clone --preserve-empty-dirs --prefix "" ...`.

Unfortunately this fails always at the same revision with the following message:

```
Found possible branch point: http://<svn>/tags/2008-03-26-1000-BINDING, 656
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/tags/2008-03-26-1000-BINDING) cc93e7405337b31d9fce7ec28ab67a9ac3af3811
Following parent with do_switch
couldn't truncate file at /usr/share/perl5/Git.pm line 1410.
```

Without the --preserve-empty-dirs flag, I can clone it successfully. Is there any workaround for this issue?

git version 2.11.0,
svn version 1.9.5

Comment: I could continue with git svn fetch till the next error. And again it continues fetching the revisions. When I let it continue fetching as many times as there are such breaks, can I be sure at the end that everthing is correctly cloned?

Comment: Is this about a one-time conversion and you only use Git thereafter, or do you want to commit back to SVN from your Git clone?

Comment: It is one-time only. We will stop using SVN after the migration.

Answer (score -1):

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout and you can also tell it to keep empty directories by giving it a commandline option that causes it to put empty `.gitignore` files in the directories to keep them.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)